# When subtracting a datetime that was converted from string, total_seconds() is wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

The `total_seconds()` is incorrect when I do this:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from pytz import timezone

timezone = timezone('Australia/Sydney')
startDate = datetime.now(timezone)
dateStr = '2020-05-18 20:12:30' # In our brain we know this time is in Sydney Time
endDate = datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone)

diff = endDate - startDate
print(diff.total_seconds()) # incorrect answer
```

When both datetime objects are datetime objects originally, and you substract them, they are right

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from pytz import timezone

timezone = timezone('Australia/Sydney')
startDate = datetime.now(timezone)
endDate = datetime.now(timezone) + timedelta(hours=2, seconds=32)

diff = endDate - startDate
print(diff.total_seconds()) # correct answer
```

How can I fix my issue ?

Comment: @TinNguyen looks like it might be `from pytz import timezone`

Comment: They dont seem to have the same offset. if you print the start and end dates, the start has an offset of `+10:00` and the end has an offset of `+10:05`. Is your total seconds thats incorrect different by about 300 seconds?

Comment: Id say be consistent in your date creation. change your startdate line to `datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone)` So that its creating a date consistnely like your end date. This will ensure they are both on the same offset. As to why the offset is different in your example i am still looking

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I added the imports

Comment: Also yes @ChrisDoyle You right. The difference is always about 5 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like all things in the horrible world of date-times, timezones and offsets this is one of these weird and wonderful things. the issue seems to stem from the fact that `pytz.timezone` will return a timezone object with several timezones.

```py
{
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=36300), datetime.timedelta(0), 'LMT'): <DstTzInfo 'Australia/Sydney' LMT+10:05:00 STD>, 
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=36000), datetime.timedelta(0), 'AEST'): <DstTzInfo 'Australia/Sydney' AEST+10:00:00 STD>, 
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=39600), datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600), 'AEDT'): <DstTzInfo 'Australia/Sydney' AEDT+11:00:00 DST>
}
```

It seems when you are passing the timezone to the now method it's picking the timezone from your choice of 3 based on probably some local TZINFO in your setup. However, when passing the timezone to replace, it's just picking the LMT which is different by 300. A quick mention about LMT:

> **Local Mean Time Today**: While Local Mean Time does not directly
>   determine civil time these days, it is still used to make sure our
>   clocks follow the Sun as closely as possible. UT1, a version of
>   Universal Time is the Local Mean Time at the prime meridian in
>   Greenwich, London. It is one of the components used to calculate
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), the time scale used to determine
>   local times worldwide.
>
> LMT is also used by astronomers around the world to time their
>   observations.

Essentially your issue spans from `datetime.now()` acting on the local timezone and `datetime.replace()` acting on the LMT timezone. So as I mentioned in my post create your dates consistently either create them both via replace (although you will still be off by 5 mins in terms of actual time, the difference will be correct.)

**UPDATE**

If you want both `datetime` objects to be in local Sydney time then you can create your stardate as you did before using `datetime.now()`. But you should create your end date from your timezone objects asking it to localize it for you like.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

timezone = timezone('Australia/Sydney')
startDate = datetime.now(timezone)
dateStr = '2020-05-18 18:52:30' # In our brain we know this time is in Sydney Time
endDate = timezone.localize(datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print(startDate, endDate, sep="\n")
diff = endDate - startDate
print(diff.total_seconds())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2020-05-18 18:51:24.722614+10:00
2020-05-18 18:52:30+10:00
65.277386
```

Comment: So how do I actually fix it in terms of the code I provided?

Comment: I don't want my time to be in Local Mean Time. I want it to be in AEST time. How can I change my unaware string to aware sydney timezone?

Comment: I have updates the answer with a code example how to get your unaware string in to local syndey timeobject

Comment: Sorry one more question. Say we have a `datetime` object which is `unaware` of the timezone. How can we convert an this unaware datetime object to an aware AEST Sydney timezone datetime object and not face this problem again

Comment: exactly the same way as you do for the string object, pass it to `timezone.localize()` cause if you look at my example thats exactly what happens here. We dont pass the string to timezone.localize, we first create a datetime object form it, which is an unaware object, we then give this to timezone to localize for us

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: this is an interesting finding! Basically, using `replace` gives an invalid result, right? Do you know of any resources when it it is ***safe*** to use `replace`? For example, I think it is fine if you use it to add UTC tzinfo to a dt obj ( `datetime.timezone.utc`).

Comment: Honestly @MrFuppes am not sure, i had never seen it before so done a little digging, but datetimes can get complex very quickly so i am not sure on the rules or implementation under the hood that decides to use LMT or AEST in this example

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: I think the answer to my comment above is: whenever you stay within the Python time zone model. `pytz` doesn't do that, so you have to `loaclize()`. I've added a link to a blog article in my answer that explains the issue a little bit, if you're interested.